# How do I make ner_crf stop adding spaces?

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition, rasa-core, crf

I've got rasa_nlu integrated into my python app.  I'm passing it a glob of characters, '${webAddress}' in this example, and I'd like to get that glob of characters back as an entity.  For some reason, ner_crf is adding spaces in the entity value, even though it is not in the response text.  How do I make it stop doing that?

I'm using the spacy_sklearn pipeline for training.  I'd expand it out to specify the individual components, but I can't find any information on how to configure individual components anyway.  I have included very similar examples in my training data (substituting some other string for webAddress), and it does recognized the entitity. Just...just...stop it with the spaces!

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:5000/parse -d '{"q":"navigate to ${webAddress}"}'
{
  "intent": {
    "name": "navigate",
    "confidence": 0.1911308126544064
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "start": 12,
      "end": 25,
      "value": "$ { webaddress }",
      "entity": "url",
      "confidence": 0.5229620578330448,
      "extractor": "ner_crf"
    }
  ],
  "text": "navigate to ${webAddress}",
  "project": "default",
  "model": "model_20190409-153615"
}
```

Comment: I fixed the part where spaces are being added.  In in the Rasa_NLU codes crf_entity_extractor.py, I found _create_entity_dict() and removed the space from the join() that creates 'value'.  I now have another problem where an uppercase leading character is being cast to lowercase.

Comment: The case issue was fixed by adding "case_sensitive: true" parameter to the configuration of the nlp_spacy component.